# for loop in contact listener drop FPS?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a scheduled function that check contacts between bodies ,that is being called every frame.

When i want to check touches between a certain `CCSprite` and `b2body` , i first check if they exist on screen, than, i run in for loop on all the sprites from the relevant kind. so ,if i have 3 dogs that i want to check contact with , i have to run each frame on all dogs sprites on screen .
Problem is that i can see its decreasing my FPS and make the game little fuzzy .(stack frames)

How can i run during the contacts on many sprites and not drop down the FPS ?

```
//in my contact check that relevant sprites are exist,than check contact
   if([self getChildByTag:1] && [self getChildByTag:300])
            {
                // run on 10 sprites and check contact
                for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
                 {
                     if( CGRectIntersectsRect ([[self getChildByTag:300+i]  boundingBox], [sprite boundingBox]))
                     //do something
                  }
```

so even when there is no contact, only the fact that i check so many conditions in frame rate cause some leaks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The getChildByTag enumerates over the children array to find the first node with a matching tag. If those nodes happen to be near the end of the children array and there are lots of children this wastes a lot of performance.

You may be better off storing these 300+i nodes in a separate array and make that array accessible via a property.

You should also store the `sprite` boundingBox locally instead of sending the boundingBox message in each iteration.

Furthermore, you'll be running this code on **every** contact event! When 10 bodies are in contact with each other, the same code runs 10 times. At least. Because under certain circumstances contactBegan may be called multiple times per frame per contacting bodies (if they have multiple contact points I believe).

It also begs the question: why do you use CGRectIntersectsRect when you already have the two contacting bodies? It seems redundant, unless you're trying to test non-physics bodies for contact.